# Angular 4 redirect after inactivity

Tags: angular, typescript

I need to make a timeout whenever you are inactive on a page. Lets say you are 20 seconds on a page without clicking something it will redirect you to the home screen.

The current code does not work for inactivity and i dont know how to make it work.

```
ngOnInit() {
// do init at here for current route.

setTimeout((router: Router) => {
    this.router.navigate(['nextRoute']);
}, 20000);  //20s
```

}

Comment: you have to define "inactivity" here ... does it mean no keypress etc

Comment: @Niladri Yes. It means that when you dont press a key or touch the touchscreen it will redirect you to the home page

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You need a timer which counts backwards and gets resetted when user action comes up. To track user action you can use a host listener:

```
 @HostListener('document:keyup', ['$event'])
 @HostListener('document:click', ['$event'])
 @HostListener('document:wheel', ['$event'])
 resetTimer () {
    // user action occured
  }
```

And a timer would be something like this:

```
  endCount = new Subject();

// end time in minutes   
private initTimer (endTime: number) {
        const interval = 1000;
        const duration = endTime * 60;

        this.subscription = Observable.timer(0, interval)
          .take(duration)
          .subscribe(value => this.render((duration - +value) * interval),
            err => { },
            () => {
              this.endCount.next();
            });
      }

      private render (count) {
        this.secondsDisplay = this.getSeconds(count);
        this.minutesDisplay = this.getMinutes(count);
      }

      private getSeconds (ticks: number) {
        const seconds = ((ticks % 60000) / 1000).toFixed(0);
        return this.pad(seconds);
      }

      private getMinutes (ticks: number) {
        const minutes = Math.floor(ticks / 60000);
        return this.pad(minutes);
      }

      private pad (digit: any) {
        return digit <= 9 ? '0' + digit : digit;
      }
```

Listen on endCount to get notified when user was inactive for a period of time.

To reset the timer:

```
resetTimer (newEndTime) {
    this.clearTimer();
    this.initTimer(newEndTime);
  }

   clearTimer () {
    if (this.subscription) {
      this.subscription.unsubscribe();
    }
   }
```

Stackblitz Example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-2rv3or

Comment: HI, I dont understand where to put that coding. Do i put it in my component.ts file or should I create a service for it?

Comment: I would use a service for the timer, that service gets injected where your logout method is present and then you subscribe to endCount and trigger logOut. Also this service gets injected into your app.component where your method with the HostListener is. There you can reset the timer. If you still have problems I can post the whole code, just let me know.

Comment: Hi, 

Could you still post the whole code? I am still having problems and cant make it happen. @J.S

Comment: Hi I was trying to implement this very solution but I am facing issues with where to place the code.... could you please guide me with that....
I am working on a website development where I want to logout the user with idle time of 20 minutes.

Comment: @niraja k here I made a stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-2rv3or hope it'll helps.

Comment: Thanks J.S. I am trying I ll update here once I am done successfully

Answer (score 4):

Try NPM module [angular-user-idle](https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular-user-idle). It may help don't create your own solutions.

How it will look in your code:

```
ngOnInit() {
  //Start watching for user inactivity.
  this.userIdle.startWatching();

  // Start watch when time is up.
  this.userIdle.onTimeout().subscribe(() => {
    this.router.navigate(['nextRoute']);
  });
}
```

[Official demo](http://angular-user-idle.rednez.com/)

Comment: Hi, This does not work. If I install the Idle package, it will disable RXJS package and visa versa. 
So it will not work.

Comment: @Mex You can try [ng2-idle](https://github.com/HackedByChinese/ng2-idle). It should work for Angular 4 as well. Example and instruction are [here](https://hackedbychinese.github.io/ng2-idle/)

Comment: This does not work when u use it in lazy loaded modules.

Answer (score 1):

Install Idlejs node module by following cmd

```
npm install --save idlejs
```

Import module and add to app.component.ts

```
import { Idle } from 'idlejs/dist';

const idle = new Idle()
  .whenNotInteractive()
  .within(60)
  .do(() => console.log('IDLE'))
  .start();
```