# Angular - Reset inactivity redirection after navigating to new page

Tags: angular, typescript

I have an Angular app, with inactivity redirection function on it, I am using code which I found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50579279/angular-4-redirect-after-inactivity).
In my app, the user is redirected to a screensaver page after 30 seconds of inactivity, so the code is almost identical (but without showing timer on screen).

Everything works great, but the issue is - that I don't want to redirect the user from some of the pages.
But when I navigate from the page with redirection to the page without redirection, the timer is still alive. How to turn it off on the each navigation?

---

My Code:

```
timeout;
...
resetTimer(endTime: number = this.endTime) {
  const interval = 1000;
  const duration = endTime * 60;

  this.timerSubscription = timer(0, interval)
    .pipe(take(duration))
    .subscribe(
      value => this.render((duration - +value) * interval),
      err => {},
      () => {
        this.timeout = setTimeout(() => {
          this.navCtrl.navigateRoot(URL_CONSTANT.SCREENSAVER, {
            animated: false
          }, 100);
        });
      }
    );
}
...
ngOnDestroy() {
  this.unsubscribe$.next();
  this.unsubscribe$.complete();
  clearTimeout(this.timeout);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should store a reference to the timeout, e.g.

```js
this.timeout = setTimeout(() => { // Do redirect }
```

Then cancel the timeout when the component is destroyed (i.e. when the user navigates away).
So add implements OnDestroy to your component class:

```
export class Xyz implements OnDestroy{ ... }
```

And add a new method called ngOnDestroy:

```js
ngOnDestroy(){
  clearTimeout(this.timeout);
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Should it look like a code I've just added to my question? Looks like it's still not working as expected

Answer (score 0):

I've figured it out, just needed to add something like `this.timerSubscription.unsubscribe();` to my `ngOnDestroy()`.

The reason why it took me so long time to understand it - it because I was working with some modals, and there was no destroy on navigation.